# opencv installation is not creating jar file in java

Tags: java, linux, opencv, jar

while installing opencv3.0 it is not creating jar file .when Iam running the opencv.sh it is saying in console

```
     Ant:                  /usr/bin/ant
     JNI:                         NO
    Java Wrappers:               NO
--  Java tests:                  NO
```

Iam thinking because of this it is not creating jar file .Please tell me how provide path for the above statements

Comment: Please specify your problem in details don't just Copy-paste the commands .

Comment: when i ran the opencv.sh  script file.It is successfully installing and buid is successfull .But jar file is not creating .

Comment: I have done it in so many ways but jar file is not creating in bin folder.Please let me know

Comment: using cmake gui also I have tried but jar file is not creating.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question.
The only thing I did is in bashrc file I have added the java path.Thats it .It is creating jar file .

Comment: i've been building opencv on linux having java installed with JAVA_HOME but i don't get the jar generated